# How to prevent app quit automatically after UI Test in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitest

I want to let the UI Test automatically lead me to some parts of my app, and then I will go with some manual testing. However, the app just quit automatically after the UI Test is done. Are there any ways to prevent this and achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

For a UI test you can simply set a breakpoint at the end of the test. Once the breakpoint is hit you can go ahead and use the debug application.